# Rcpp C++ truncates decimal places no matter what

Tags: r, decimal, rcpp, truncate, digits

- Platform: Redhat Enterprise 7.5 on AWS instance with RStudio Server.
- Reproducible Code: I apologize in advance for not providing code because if I simplify the function into a reproducible function, I know it will work and produce the expected results.
- Case:
- I have a function coded in C++ using Rcpp, the function includes a division by the product of some subtraction of very small quantities. For example, it first executes some subtraction like (.0012345678 - .0012345677), and then based on this example, the function should divide by .0000000001, but the function truncates the quantities in the subtraction (.001234 - .001234) and produces zero and consequently inf as an output of the division by zero.

  - My question is: is there anything that I should be aware of in Rcpp setting to get it to produce at least 15 decimal places so that the subtraction does not produce inf or nan. I have coded another much smaller function and it works just fine. However, no matter what I do, the much bigger function truncates the double data types numbers going into the division and the subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and there reference therein -- you are at the "epsilon" precision limit here.

Rcpp uses the same `double` type as R and every other C-based program.  There is also `long double`, but what you may really want is an arbitrary / multiple precision library such as [GNU mpfr](https://www.mpfr.org/) which also has an [R package Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rmpfr).

Comment: Thanks Dirk. But any alternative to Rmpfr since I get the following error trying to * installing *source* package ‘gmp’ ...
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gmp’
* removing ‘/home/ec2-user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/gmp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gmp’ is not available for package ‘Rmpfr’

Comment: Note the entry in `DESCRIPTION` which states `SystemRequirements: gmp (>= 4.2.3), mpfr (>= 3.0.0)`. Installation from source requires these; each Linux distro or Brew should have it.  Note that you need the `-dev` or `-devel` packages to build against this.